# I am trying to click on element using array using xpath but it gives me "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" error message

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to loop to the list of elements and using the loop i am trying to click on each of the checkbox's

```
*totalCheckboxCount = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='checkbox-example']//*[@type='checkbox']")
    for i in range:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.// *[@ id='checkbox-example']//*[@ type='checkbox'])["+int(i)+"]").click()
```

---

But i am getting `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` message, However i used selenium C# and java but it was working there but in python is not working.

Comment: you are also better of using pythons f-strings `f"text {variable}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your "i" into a string by using the str() function. Please see the code below:

```
string = 'Hi '

for i in range(0,21,1):
    print(string + str(i))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Hi 0
Hi 1
Hi 2
Hi 3
Hi 4
Hi 5
Hi 6
Hi 7
Hi 8
Hi 9
Hi 10
Hi 11
Hi 12
Hi 13
Hi 14
Hi 15
Hi 16
Hi 17
Hi 18
Hi 19
Hi 20
```

However, it seems to me that your code will never work in Python because of the way in which a few other things are written (such as the "for i in range:"). It seems that it's syntax is from another programming language.

Answer (score 3):

you are doing `int(i)+"]"` which is throwing your error

change that to `str(int(i))+"]"`